# How to calculate null among other data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count how much NULL data gets to the row with the contents of "resuss"

Like that:

| open_date | m+ | id | flag | time hibernate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202203 | 202205 | ax1 | resuss | 1 |
| 202203 | 202209 | ax1 | resuss | 3 |
| 202203 | 202206 | ay2 | resuss | 2 |
| 202203 | 202209 | ay2 | null | 3 |
| 202203 | 202209 | az3 | null | 6 |
| 202203 | 202209 | av4 | resuss | 5 |

DataTable is:

| open_date | m+ | id | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202203 | 202204 | ax1 | null |
| 202203 | 202205 | ax1 | resuss |
| 202203 | 202206 | ax1 | null |
| 202203 | 202207 | ax1 | null |
| 202203 | 202208 | ax1 | null |
| 202203 | 202209 | ax1 | resuss |
| 202203 | 202204 | ay2 | null |
| 202203 | 202205 | ay2 | null |
| 202203 | 202206 | ay2 | resuss |
| 202203 | 202207 | ay2 | null |
| 202203 | 202208 | ay2 | null |
| 202203 | 202209 | ay2 | null |
| 202203 | 202204 | az3 | null |
| 202203 | 202205 | az3 | null |
| 202203 | 202206 | az3 | null |
| 202203 | 202207 | az3 | null |
| 202203 | 202208 | az3 | null |
| 202203 | 202209 | az3 | null |
| 202203 | 202204 | av4 | null |
| 202203 | 202205 | av4 | null |
| 202203 | 202206 | av4 | null |
| 202203 | 202207 | av4 | null |
| 202203 | 202208 | av4 | null |
| 202203 | 202209 | av4 | resuss |

My script SQL like that, but this is false:

```
SELECT
    opendate, m+, id, sum(case when flag is null than 1 else 0 end) as timeHibernate
FROM dataTable
WHERE flag = "resuss"
GROUP BY opendate, m+, id
```

This false, because column of *timeHibernate* count 0

Please help me

Comment: You want COUNT(), not SUM(). SUM() produces a total by adding, and you can't add NULL values.

Comment: @KenWhite:  I know the difference between sum() and count(), so I use case when than to give a value of 1 to be able to do the sum

Comment: @rejaeja use ifnull(flag,0) then it will work.

Comment: @Manoj ya, its work, but, can't solve my problem

Comment: @rejaeja give us the exact o/p that you looking for. Because the data what you have shared i/p & o/p is not matching.

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result - [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can simply adding "flag" into group by and also replace sum() into count(*)
I think it may return your expected result.

```
SELECT
opendate, m+, id,flag , Count(*) as timeHibernate
FROM dataTable
WHERE flag = "resuss"
GROUP BY opendate, m+, id,flag
```

---

Otherwise, I think you can also try replacing

```
case when flag is null then 1 else 0 end
```

into

```
case when flag = '' then 1 else 0 end
```

or

```
case when flag = 'null' then 1 else 0 end
```

According to the given information, 
It may because the flag 'Null' may not really a null values.
That cause the (case when) return a diffrent result intead of your expected result. 
If it still not working you can also test in a smaller scale or more simple statment like

```
select * from dataTable
where flag = ''\flag = 'null'\flag is null
```

to test out the how to filtering the null values

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    open_date, m+, id, SUM(CASE WHEN flag IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS timeHibernate
FROM dataTable
WHERE flag = "resuss" OR flag IS NULL
GROUP BY open_date, m+, id
```